# How to force stack to re-fetch urls in a snapshot

Tags: haskell-stack

I have a snapshot.yaml that looks like this

```
resolver: lts-14.0

packages:
- url: https://github.com/llvm-hs/llvm-hs/archive/refs/heads/llvm-9.zip
  subdirs:
  - llvm-hs
  - llvm-hs-pure
```

I have pushed to the project at the end of that .zip URL, and I have manually downloaded the zip and looked to ensure that the changes I made are in fact present there.

Stack is using a stale previously downloaded copy of the zip. I cannot find it, and I have tried for some time. I even completely blew away my ~/.stack and set everything up again from scratch, and the stale cached version of the zip persists! Help?